# Get Post Share Statistics

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm testing the version 202307 of the Linkedin API wiht the Protocol 2.0.0

I want to get the stats of one posts doing the following get request

`https://api.linkedin.com/rest/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3AID&shares[0]=urn%3Ali%3Ashare%3A7087827475862315008`

But I'm getting the following message in Postman. Has somebody now what can be the issue ? I've been reading the documentation of linkedin and seems to the paramater be correct passing the `shares[0]=ID`

[image]